Compiler that compiles to a Universal Turing Machine (UTM) tape program?
With Universal Turing Machines I mean the Turing Machines with fixed transition functions, proven by Yurii Rogozhin in his paper "Small universal Turing machines" to be capable of universal computation by specifying the program as part of the input tape, such as UTM(24, 2) or UTM(2,18).
Does a compiler transforming a higher level programming language to the program representation on tape that one of these (specific) machines accepts exist?

there is brainfck which is a programming language based on turing machines and some transpilers which compile to brainfck.

Universal Turing Machines interpret programs in the form of tag systems on their tape, so this is not directly applicable
